# How to integrate my Java application as a consumer?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a Java application. How do I use it as consumer of messages in activemq?  Do I need to write any code where I will be passing my name of java application to list it as a consumer?

Or do I need to integrate any software (like camel, spring) which will help me to achieve this. Right now what I am looking for is that this Java application needs to be called when activemq gets populated with a message.

If I need to integrate something into my activemq please put some links which will clearly explain how to go about the integration.

PS I am new to activemq and I am super dependent on your help .

Comment: Related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015882/activemq-publisher-subscriber-hello-world-example

Comment: If you are working on a Spring application. Or have knowledge of how to work with it, it's pretty simple. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jms.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a Spring application. Or have knowledge of how to work with it, it's pretty simple.

The configuration would be something like this:

```
<bean id="messageListener" class="jmsexample.ExampleListener" />


<bean id="jmsContainer"     class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
</bean>
```

Look at the documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jms.html

Comment: OP and me both are working on same task.Spring is a framework written on Java.Basically we are not Java developers.So can you suggest in another way. you mention some XML code,where will I found that file.