# How to send message using tcp/ip ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I am looking for a example ActiveMQ using TCP/IP to send and receive messages. I have tried but I could not get one. I think ActiveMQ documentation is neither clear nor enough. Would you please let me know one?
Your answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ *IS* TCP/IP.

Suggestion: try some of the examples that come with your installation:

- http://activemq.apache.org/examples.html

Pick one example that's closest to how you actually want to use ActiveMQ, and feel free to post back with questions about some specific thing you're trying.

Besides the Apache documentation, this link might also help:

- [ACTIVEMQ- publisher subscriber hello world example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015882/activemq-publisher-subscriber-hello-world-example)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it. It looks helpful.